Get Request In Angular Seems To Not Resolve, Despite Having No Error
I'm working on a small project and i'm trying to makke my backend and frontend communicate data via HTTP Requests. My back in a spring application, and is only posting data for a coloured grid at the endpoint "http://localhost:8080/api/grid/generate?size=4" ( Hardcoded for now ).
I checked and the post is resolving itself, and posting where it should :
{
  "grid": [
    [
      {
        "color": "#9a8ca3",
        "gridPosition": [0, 0]
      },
      {
        "color": "#6382f1",
        "gridPosition": [0, 1]
      },
      {
        "color": "#9f4f77",
        "gridPosition": [0, 2]
      },
      {
        "color": "#6382f1",
        "gridPosition": [0, 3]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "color": "#0632ea",
        "gridPosition": [1, 0]
      },
      {
        "color": "#9a8ca3",
        "gridPosition": [1, 1]
      },
      {
        "color": "#9f4f77",
        "gridPosition": [1, 2]
      },
      {
        "color": "#5e6c0f",
        "gridPosition": [1, 3]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "color": "#9a8ca3",
        "gridPosition": [2, 0]
      },
      {
        "color": "#5e6c0f",
        "gridPosition": [2, 1]
      },
      {
        "color": "#FFFFFF",
        "gridPosition": [2, 2]
      },
      {
        "color": "#0632ea",
        "gridPosition": [2, 3]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "color": "#74e57b",
        "gridPosition": [3, 0]
      },
      {
        "color": "#0632ea",
        "gridPosition": [3, 1]
      },
      {
        "color": "#74e57b",
        "gridPosition": [3, 2]
      },
      {
        "color": "#74e57b",
        "gridPosition": [3, 3]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "emptyCellPosition": [2, 2]
}

Now for the "tricky" part : In angular, to get my grid I wrote this in a corresponding service :
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CellComponent } from '../components/cell/cell.component';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GridService {
  private readonly apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/grid';
  private constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  // Generate grid from backend API
  public generateGrid(size: number): Observable<{ grid: CellComponent[][], emptyCellPosition: [number, number] }> {
    console.log("Url used: ",`${this.apiUrl}/generate?size=${size.toString()}` );
    return this.http.get<{ grid: CellComponent[][], emptyCellPosition: [number, number] }>(`${this.apiUrl}/generate?size=${size.toString()}`);
  }

this is what i wrote in my grid component :
  public constructor(private readonly gridService: GridService) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initGrid();
  }

  private initGrid(): void {
    this.gridService.generateGrid(this.size).subscribe({
      next: ({ grid, emptyCellPosition }) => {
        this.grid = grid;
        this.emptyCellPosition = emptyCellPosition;
        this.score = 0;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Error generating grid:', err);
      }
    });
  }

I can't seem to find an error anywhere, and analysing the "Network" in my rendered page does not show any get request being made. Am I blind or did I made a rookie mistake in Angular ?
I checked for the URL if it was not correct, I tried hardcoding it but it did not change anything. I also checked using the type any, and it also did not give proper results. I also checked if the get function worked and gave back an observable, which it did ("Observable2").

Did you check if the code inside the next callback from the Observable is called? Does your component use change detection strategy OnPush?

I think your'e on the right track ! I'm not using OnPush strategy, but no log seems to be done in my subscribe. I also added a "complete" section to log for a success, and a log in the "next" section, but none of them were called.

Your data from the API call, should return an array of objects, but it is returning an array of arrays (which contains objects), if you did not account for this in your HTML, maybe the render is not happening. You can use the array method flat which flattens array of arrays so that you have a single array.
  public constructor(private readonly gridService: GridService) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initGrid();
  }

  private initGrid(): void {
    this.gridService.generateGrid(this.size).subscribe({
      next: ({ grid, emptyCellPosition }) => {
        this.grid = grid.flat(); // <- changed here!
        this.emptyCellPosition = emptyCellPosition;
        this.score = 0;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Error generating grid:', err);
      }
    });
  }


Thanks, I did in fact propagate the structure Cell[][] to this component, as grid is also a Cell[][] . But flat() seems rather interesting if I want to switch up my way of doing things !

@ThomasLeDret if you could share a stackblitz with the issue replicated, it would be good for debugging

I don't really know how to do that but i can try

The answer was actually more simple than I expected. After some research in the provided environnement for the front, I found out i had an import of provideHttpClientTesting in my app.config.ts. This prevented my front-end to do actual requests, which it now does.
Thank you for the attention you've given to my problem !
